# the background image doesn't work on chrome but it works on edge

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm using Yii framework and this is a view page

```
 <style>
    header{
            height: 85%;
            background-image:url('C:/xampp/htdocs/moic/situations-master1/backend/web/images/2.jpg') !important;
            background-size: cover;
        }
   </style>
    <header>
        any data here
    </header>
```

Comment: URL should be relative to the website URL, not folder directory structure. And what does this have to do with PHP? This is a CSS issue.

Comment: but it works well with microsoft edge browser ?! this is included in a php file

Comment: but it worked when I changed to relative :"D thank you

Comment: Yea, don't go on how well Microsoft works, go with how well Chrome and Firefox work. Microsoft are famous for not following international standards. IE is the spawn of the devil, and whilst Edge is better it's still not perfect.

Comment: okay, thanks for information :'D

Answer (score 0):

changed to relative path, Chrome doesn't seem to work well with absolute